# Error during installation of plpythonu (postresql & linux)

Tags: linux, postgresql-9.1

i'm trying to run this command `createlang plpythonu dbanem`
but i have an error

```
createlang: language installation failed: ERROR:  could not open extension control file "/usr/share/postgresql/9.1/extension/plpythonu.control"
```

how can i install plpythonu?? (i'm just starting out with linux) 
can you help me??

Answer (score 2):

```
apt-get install postgresql-plpython
```